# Reference an array which was created by another function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, function, reference

I have the below Struct

```
struct KStruct {
let SongTitle: String
let SongLyrics: String
let ESongTitle: String

 init(SongTitle: String, SongLyrics:String, ESongTitle: String) {
    self.SongTitle =  SongTitle
    self.SongLyrics = SongLyrics
    self.ESongTitle = ESongTitle
}
func match(string:String) -> Bool {
    let lowerCaseKeyword = string.lowercaseString
    return SongTitle.lowercaseString.containsString(lowerCaseKeyword) || ESongTitle.containsString(lowerCaseKeyword)

    }
}
```

I am converting this as an array and I am populating this array in a loop like below in the viewDidload function

```
let keerthanaiArray = KStruct(SongTitle : songTitleT!, SongLyrics : songLyricsT!,
                                    ESongTitle : EsongTitleT!)
```

Now I am trying to refer this Array in an another function filterContentForSearchText

But I am unable to do so as the array is not recognized outside of its own function.  How do I read this array in another function.  Please help

Comment: Why not use the array as Global for that class.

Comment: How to declare the array as Global.  I couldn't successfully declare.  Please help

Comment: Your `keerthanaiArray` isn't an array – it's a `KStruct`. Sounds like you just want to [declare a property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) in your class. Btw, property names and parameter labels should be `lowerCamelCase`, not `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: I am trying to create an array with the KStruct declaration.  I am reading a database file containing the title,lyrics,etitle and trying to populate in this array in a loop.  am I not doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array as global. On you code `keerthanaiArray`is a **KStruct** type object, not an array. Have a look at the following:

```
var keerthanaiArray:[KStruct]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if KeerthanaigalDB.open()
    {
        var i = 0
        let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM KEERTHANAIGAL ORDER BY ROWID DESC"
        let results:FMResultSet? = KeerthanaigalDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        if (results != nil)
        {
            while results!.next()
            {
                let songTitleT = results?.stringForColumn("SONGNAME")  as? String ?? ""
                arrayData1.append(songTitleT!)
                let songLyricsT = results?.stringForColumn("SONGLYRICS")  as? String ?? ""
                arrayData2.append(songLyricsT!)
                let EsongTitleT = results?.stringForColumn("ESONGNAME")  as? String ?? ""


                keerthanaiArray.append(KStruct(SongTitle : songTitleT, SongLyrics : songLyricsT,
                    ESongTitle : EsongTitleT))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the above way to have a default value of empty **String**. So that you can avoid the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` issue.

Comment: I am trying to load the array within the viewdidload function.  Where will I declare the class ArrayClass?  If I declare outside of my viewdidload function, then I wouldn't be able to reference the variables songTitleT!, songLyricsT! and EsongTitleT! as these variables are populated by reading a database within the viewdidload function

Comment: class ArrayClass is just an example. You should declare your keerthanaiArray in the corresponding view-controller class on which viewdidload() you are populating the array. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks now I am free of compilation errors, now when I run the code, I got the error " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at the keerthanaiArray.append statement :(

Comment: The songTitleT, songLyricsT and EsongTitleT are used with an "!", for this any of them can have a nil. Thats the reason you are getting the error.

Comment: If I remove the ! then I get the error " value of optional string 'String?' not unwrapped; did u mean to use '!' or '?' "

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Also it will be better for you if you can have some idea about optional and nil coalescing operator . Have a look at this doc. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/247/optionals#t=201607301845463121338